# Passing pointers to arrays between C and C#

Tags: c#, c, pointers

Forgive me if the title is unclear or incomplete but I don't know how else to phrase it.

I have created a C DLL and am in the process of building a C# UI to call various functions of this DLL. This library of mine reads some huge lookup tables (1.43 GB) and performs some statistical analysis. I currently just call the C functions and pass some parameters and get the output back to C#.

But the catch is every time I call the C DLL, I have to read these lookup tables from Hard disk. 
To make the program more efficient I am planning to create a prepare function in the DLL which will read all the the tables one time and return a pointer to the C# UI which in turn will pass this pointer to the C function to use avoiding the multiple reads from HDD.

My questions are as follows:

- Will this work? Will not modern operating system garbage collectors
  reclaim the memory the prep function allocates once the C DLL returns
  the pointer? Making the pointer effective pointing to junk?
- Will it be better to write a module to load the lookup table to memory in the C# UI and pass it to C DLL for use?
- My scenario is specific to C/C# but in general when building an application using multiple languages, does passing data like this pose
  any additional risks I might be overlooking?

Comment: Maybe consider a service.

Comment: If the DLL remains loaded, the pointer should remain valid.  If you unload the DLL, you need someone else to pontificate.  A DLL is not a program (or process); memory stays allocated while a program runs under normal circumstances — where DLLs are not unloaded.

Comment: I would avoid having C# load this into the process memory space, you have a 2GB limit (for 32-bit) and a 4GB limit (for 64-bit). If you want to do something like that, I would look at Memory Mapped Files.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not sure what you mean.
`[DllImport(@"c:\MethodNameLibrary.dll")]
   private static extern int methodName(int b);` i use this to create a the DLL function call and then use it like a normal function? I don't explicitly load or unload the DLL could you point me to some literature on this

Comment: I said I can't help much — I've never knowingly coded a single line of C# code in my life.  In my C-thinking world, `static extern` is a contradiction in terms.  From where I sit, with essentially zero knowledge of C#, `DllImport` is responsible for ensuring that the DLL is available (loaded).  I don't know whether some destructor would unload it — I don't know anything significant about memory management in C#.  If my advice seems irrelevant or inaccurate, ignore it — it is written in ignorance of C# specifically, though the ideas are basically valid in C.

Comment: If your data can be accessed as a Stream or by Offset (random), then do consider what @Ron Beyer proposed. See the [MemoryMappedFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) definition and operations. I wouldn't worry about those pointers in your C DLL.

Comment: @Jimi how does that help ? How can I pass the mapped memory file from c# to c? And how will the mapped memory file overcome the 2gb and 4gb problem mentioned by Ron?

Comment: Keep in mind the core DLL is pure c

Comment: A `MemoryMappedFile` doesn't need to be loaded in memory as a whole. You can acces it in chunks. The size of a chunk can vary. It's also multi-process safe (even concurrent accesses). You can operate on a chunk as a stream, or, guess what, with pointers. Much depends on the nature of your files and how you work on them. The nature of the exchange of pointers between C# code and a C Dll is known to you only. Maybe uncalled for, but, do you really need the Dll to access the Disc? Couldn't it just perform the calculations on, say, data as byte arrays preprocessed/preselected by the C# code?

Comment: @Jimi I can manipulate the tables any way I want.. they are all n dimentional tables of 64bit data types but they are stored as single dimentional byte arrays, my second question was this only..loading data in c# and passing it to c. But Ron pointed out a limit on the size of 4Gb. This can be a deal breaker. The C dll is already using multi processing internally.

Comment: The memory limit does not apply to `MemoryMappedFiles`. Unless you need to create a byte array of 4GB :) (Wait, no, right?). Once you have mapped it, only the requested view(s) is(are) loaded in memory (managed by the System, in a quite efficient way). Give it a look. Since you are already used to this type of operations on files (by pointers), it should be quite straightforward. It is, in many ways, the same thing.

Comment: I guess I can reachitect the DLL to lower memory required and process data in a different order.. then I can use MemoryMappedFiles. Let me try ! Otherwise I'll turn the DLL into a service.. which is too complicated...